# Django unable to get model property Sum of objects in template

Tags: django

I want to get sum of all the prices available in my model. I have  gone through this link [Sum of objects' prices in Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51287539/sum-of-objects-prices-in-django-template)
but I was not able to get my answer when I am running in a shell, I am getting the correct output, but from the template point unable to get the correct output

```
**shell**


>>> from tasks.models import Task
>>> from django.db.models import Sum
>>> Task.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('price'))
{'price__sum': 2.0}
```

**Model:**

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Avg


class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    price = models.FloatField(max_length=5,default='0.00',editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    @property
    def get_price_total(self):
        total=Task.objects.all().aggregate(Avg("price"))
        print(total)
        return total
```

**Views**

```
def query(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.all()


    form = TaskForm()

    if request.method =='POST':
        form=TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return redirect('/')
    print("Price",Task.get_price_total)
    context = {'tasks':tasks,'form':form,'Totalprice':Task.get_price_total}
    return render(request,'tasks/query.html',context)
```

Output at the console is ( and same is getting printed in the template )

```
Django version 3.0.7, using settings 'todo.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Price <property object at 0x000002D3301502C0>
[29/Sep/2020 22:33:53] "GET /query/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2473
```

Can some help me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `get_price_total` a `classmethod`, it does not make sense to be an instance method or property because it aggregates data from all instances of the model.

```
@classmethod
def get_price_total(cls):
    total = cls.objects.aggregate(total=Sum("price"))['total']
    print(total)
    return total
```

Then use it in your view/context

```
context = {'total_price': Task.get_price_total(), ...}
```

Comment: They can also make it property if it is a must: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128573/using-property-on-classmethods

Comment: @Iain Shelvington Thank you very much, for helping, worked like a charm